# Cannot install pip in python 3 mac OSX Big Sur

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, zsh, macos-big-sur

I recently installed Python 3 and when I wanted to check the version, it says it is Python 2.7

As I understand it, the new MacOS comes with Python 2.7 so that seems to not be the issue.

So when I want to install pip it keeps saying

```
command not found
```

How do I install pip then? Help me please

Comment: Be careful: `python` and `pip` usually refer to installations of python *2*, not python *3*. You need to use `python3` and `pip3`.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the reminder. I got it now. Python3 has to be declared as Python3 and it works with only pip3 not pip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
 pip3 install package-name
```

If you still get the same error message, refer to the following link to get detailed instructions on pip installation on macOS:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-pip-in-macos/

Comment: The provided link works for me! Thanks!  I had to install pip3 within Python3. That is what I did and it says it is installed now. Only that every time I want to run my terminal i have to make sure i run python3 so that it wont confuse with Python 2.7

Comment: just use python3 scriptname.py in your console, or you create an venv to make sure, you always use the python --version u want

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem, what I did was to install Homebrew first.

```
$ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

then add it to the path

after that you can install Python 3 by typing the following command :

```
$ brew install python
```

to check if Python3 has been installed type :

```
$ python3 --version
```

Answer (score 0):

I would get in the habit of using a virtual environment for every project. Treat the stock system installations as an implementation detail of the OS, not something you should be modifying directly.

You can start with something as simple as

```
# Ignore the system-installed Python 2
python3 -mvenv venv
. venv/bin/activate
```

Now `python` and `pip` will each refer to the correct versions found in the virtual environment.